# jQuery - aria-controls vs data attributes to identify/select DOM element - which is preferred method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, accessibility, wai-aria

I am designing a web page and want to be able to hide/show certain divs based on the user clicking filter buttons.

I have seen DOM elements with aria-controls and also with data-attributes (I could add either to my div elements in order to later find them with jQuery and show/hide them).

When it comes to selecting DOM elements with jQuery, I wondered if there is a difference between the two methods?

I've Googled [aria-controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848872(v=vs.85).aspx) but haven't managed to work it out.

Which would be the preferred method (and why)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When it comes to selecting DOM elements with jQuery, I wondered if there is a difference between the two methods?

From a performance standpoint, no. They are both just attributes, and I don't know of any special mechanism that boosts performance of finding elements by `aria-*` attributes.

From an ideological standpoint, yes.

The `aria-*` attributes are meant to enhance the accessibility of JavaScript heavy pages. If the purpose of your JavaScript is to enhance accessibility then it might make sense to select elements based on the `aria` attributes. If you just want to identify a user interface component, then using `data` attributes might be more descriptive. If there is an accessibility feature in newer browsers that you want supported in older browsers then JavaScript selecting elements based on `aria` attributes makes sense, because you are creating a pollyfill that would most likely require the use of `aria` attributes even in supported browsers.

I would use these guidelines:

1. Creating pollyfills for accessibility features in older browsers (select by `aria`)
2. Building your own accessibility enhancements (select by `aria`)
3. Want to identify user interface elements without regards to accessibility, or having nothing to do with accessibility (use `data` attributes)

ARIA controls are meant for accessibility, and `data` attributes are meant for your own custom use that has no meaning to the browser, but has meaning to your application. Ultimately this is the differentiating factor.